# Disable drop shadows around windows or the menu bar on OS X

Tags: macos

[Nocturne](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/) has an option for disabling shadows around windows. But it's only available in night mode, and changing the mode (like when opening the application) causes an annoying screen flash animation. There's no way to disable the shadow under the menu bar either.

[MacThemes Forum / Removing the menubar dropshadow](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16808556) has a link to a .psd for making special desktop backgrounds that cancel out the shadow under the menu bar. But it only works if that area of the desktop picture has a low enough brightness.

Some applications that cover the desktop (like [DeskShade](http://macrabbit.com/deskshade/)) also cover the menu bar's shadow. That's not a real solution though.

<s>Unsanity's [ShadowKiller](http://unsanity.com/haxies/shadowkiller) stopped working in either 10.5 or 10.6</s>. *(It does still work on 10.7.2, but the website says "NOT compatible with Mac OS X 10.6 Leopard", and I couldn't get it to work on a 10.6 installation.)*

Related: [How do I decrease the window shadow in Mac OS X? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/126374/how-do-i-decrease-the-window-shadow-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Why do you hate the shadows so much and/or what's the need to disabling them?

Comment: @Cawas They're just too big and ugly. The same sort of applies for that blue outline around selected elements and the blue glow in Exposé, but the shadows are by far the worst.

Comment: fair enough. I thought there might be another reason. :P

Comment: @Cawas who cares why? does there need to be a reason why someone wants to do something? I'm fairly sure the initial desire was succinctly described in enough detail that it should enable you to divulge any useful information.

Comment: @airtonix Nope, it wasn't described at all. The question have been heavily edited, maybe partially thanks to my comment. And I cared why because there might be a functional reason, to which I might want to disable too. Since it's only aesthetical, I don't care about this. They don't bother me. So, at first, the reasoning behind so much effort into something so minor intrigued me.

Comment: @Cawas I thought the point of this site was to remain objective when providing answers. Essentially you are saying that instead of just giving an answer that addresses the question with a simple solution, you instead seek to reform the question away from topics you don't care about or like.

Comment: @airtonix I've asked way after it was answered and accepted already. It was just a personal curiosity that, coincidentally, many other people might have. The point isn't "remain objective" at all. **The point of this site is being informative**. "Remaining objective" is just a mean, quite important and should be the most used, but not the only one.

Comment: @Cawas I have window snapping enabled in bettertouchtool and the shadow overlaps when two windows are side-by-side.

Comment: @John2496 there you go, that might be reason enough! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! It's working perfectly on Snow Leopard (Mac Mini Core Duo @1.83 GHz).

@Lri After launching Shadowkiller, it just toggles on/off the shadow visible status and then quits itself… Never stays open.

Answer (score 2):

Unsanity's ShadowKiller *is* in fact working in 10.6, I am using it right now. (Don't know if it causes system instabuility or something).

Comment: I did not do anything special. It has always worked fine for me without any problems. Havn't tried APE. (Perhaps you should make a new user and try to install it). Or try to delete cache files (Library/Caches) which I had to do once after another problem. Just ask me other questions if you want to know anything more about my system. Maybe it is a hardware problem, my computer is from 2008.

Comment: That was strange. And after a clean install. (Hope I did hot wast to much time of yours). Yes I use the 1.3 from 2006. Another thing I probably shoud mention is that I had some problems upgrading from Leopard to Snow Lepoard. Not huge ones but in about 2 months (until some upgrade I think) I had some annoying bugs. I've heard others with a similar experiance. Can't really elaborate on exactly what it was since I don't remember all the details. Maybe It had something to do with that I had a lot of software installed, I really don't know.

Comment: Anyways. I am really not faking the fact that ShadowKiller has been working just fine with my computer for 10 months now (when I upgraded to Snow Leopard). The only slightly annoying thing is that Wine seems better supported on Leopard... I know there are services where you can upload pictures for free. If you know any I can upload a screenshot. (So that you can be extra sure that I am not faking). Just give me the name of such a webpage, really. I really was not aware that ShadowKiller had annoyances with Snow Leopard. I probably was just lucky.

Comment: I don't know what Rosetta is. I am definately not using it.

Comment: You can send me an email if you feel like it (and I can send you screenshots). Look at my user and you will find it.

Comment: I see. Yes, good to know in case I want to install some old crap :P (I'm an old Solaris fan btw). Yes shadows is probably something one can learn to live with. I guess its something of the onus of using an OS not first hand designed for programmers and sysadmins. At least nowadays osx doesn't by default comes with a fun racer-game where you controll a small dinosaur (it did once).